# How to get the string instance in guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, guice

Lets say I have binded my strings in guice like this

```
bind(String.class).annotatedWith(MasterDatabase.class).toInstance("integration");
```

If I have the handler to `injector` for this module, how would I get back the value binded through the annotation name? Here I wanted the string value associated with `MasterDatabase` annotation

Comment: BTW, using `bindConstant()` to bind constants is more idiomatic: `bindConstant().annotatedWith(MasterDatabase.class).to("integration")`. Same result, but looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you'd normally use constructor injection using the annotation:

```
@Inject
public SomeType(@MasterDatabase String databaseName)
```

Or you could explicitly request it from the injector:

```
String databaseName = injector.getInstance(Key.get(String.class,
                                                   MasterDatabase.class));
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The first option injecting in constructor was not feasible as I had to get this in a Junit test class and it does not allow constructor with parameters. The second one fits the bill.

Comment: @NandishA: There are other alternatives for injecting dependencies in tests - look at https://code.google.com/p/guiceberry/ for example.